# Include a struct which include a CList in a CMap

Tags: c++, mfc, clist

I have a `struct` which includes a `CList` which which I want to create a `CMap` with. However when I compile I get an error:

> Error C2280 `CRecipeNode::RECIPENODE::RECIPENODE(const CRecipeNode::RECIPENODE &)`: attempting to reference a deleted function

```
struct RECIPENODE {
    CString name;
    CList<CString> children;
};
typedef CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, RECIPENODE, RECIPENODE> CRecipeNodeMap;
CRecipeNodeMap nodeMap;
```

Any clues or advice would be welcomed.

I would like to use `CList` if at all possible, but if not I guess I will fall back on `std::vector`.

Comment: The error message indicates that the code generated from the class template attempts to make a copy of `RECIPENODE` (which it can't, presumably because `CList` doesn't provide a copy c'tor). To fix this you'll have to replace the fourth template type argument to `CMap` with something that won't generate functions that take values by copy (e.g. `RECIPENODE&`).

Comment: Somewhat OT: I'd get rid of those antique MFC containers such as `CList` and `CMap` and replace them with standard C++ containers such as `std::list` and `std::map` etc.